# SQL-server DateTime Format -- Monday, the Thirty-First of July, 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to have a date format like this

```
Monday, the Thirty-First of July, 2000.
```

I tried to have that pattern but i am not getting date in text .

I can get only `31 july, 2000`.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_DateString 
(
    -- input parameter
    @date datetime2
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(100)
    DECLARE @day as varchar(50)

    set @day = 
            case DATEPART(day, @date)
                when 1 then 'First' 
                when 2 then 'Second'

                when 31 then 'Thirty-First'
                else '<add other>'
            end

    SELECT @result = cast(DATENAME(dw,@date) as varchar) + 
        ', the ' + 
        CAST(@day as varchar) + 
        ' of ' + 
        CAST(DATENAME(MONTH, @date) as varchar) + 
        ', ' + 
        CAST(YEAR(@date) as varchar)

    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Comment: What do you mean 'short way' ?

Comment: to have it in 2 to 3 lines.\

Comment: For what ? Beauty Code ;-)